# How to get a deployed contract instance in truffle console that was deployed without a migration?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, console, truffle-deployment

I have a contract deployed with truffle to a testrpc local testnet.
This contract has has a function that deploys a new contract.

This new contract I can check the address in the testrpc console similar to this:

```
  Transaction: 0x85a7f17406536dd9618c6647d7d0595a2cee7e7e065ffc08a99e58aa5473ab71
  Contract created: 0x1104c5adf4476aec333ee687c725eacc8d417a7c
  Gas usage: 2642382
  Block Number: 7
  Block Time: Mon Feb 26 2018 19:27:25 GMT+0900 (JST)
```

But how can I use this new contract in the truffle console to interact with?
The json file of the contract (the ABI etc) was created in truffle's `build` directory, but because the contract is not migrated I cannot use this command:

```
MyNewContract.deployed().then(_app => { app = _app })
app.showMeTheMoney()
```

Does anyone how, in the truffle console, I can interact with contracts deployed through other contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually modify the contract file in the build directory to include the address, but it will get overwritten eventually, so it's not a good way to do this.

Moreover `deployed()` is meant to be used in the sense of a singleton. If your contract is not a singleton then you shouldn't query it via `deployed()`.

If you have the following constellation: contract A (singleton) instantiates contract B then you can store the reference(s) to B in A and query it from JavaScript.

**Example**

```
contract A {
    B[] public arrayOfBs;
    function create() returns (B) {
        B b = new B();
        arrayOfBs.push(b);
        return b;
    }
}

deployer.deploy(A);
...
A.deployed()
    .then(a => {return a.arrayOfBs(idx)})
    .then(bAddr => {return B.at(b)})
    .then(b => {b.showMeTheMoney()})
```

If B should be a singleton, then you need to change your migration script and deploy it like this.

```
deployer.deploy(A); 
deployer.deploy(B);
```

Then you'll be able to query it via `B.deployed()`.

Comment: Is there any truffle function with which j can obtain an instance of a custom deployed contract?

Comment: Yes. Just like in web3, you can use Contract.at(addr).

Comment: But you mean that it's required to save the reference in contract A? Can that saved reference also be in an array of references? Could you give a small example how to save the reference of contract B in A, since B will be a lot and A only one.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you can sketch your contracts, maybe I can give you a better example.

Comment: Dear @ivicaa Thanks for the great answer.
I tried implementing your answer, but I ran into another problem. I have opened a new question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41023/instance-ataddr-is-not-a-function-in-truffle-console
It would be really cool if you could have a look!

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone how, in the truffle console, I can interact with contracts deployed 
>   through other contracts?

To see the list of contracts already deployed on the Truffle Develop network, this command works:

```
truffle(develop)> networks [--clean]

Network: develop (id: 4447)
  Migrations: 0xfb88de099e13c3ed21f80a7a1e49f8caecf10df6
  MyNewContract: 0xf204a4ef082f5c04bb89f7d5e6568b796096735a
```