# "instance.at(addr) is not a function" in truffle console (access to non-migrated contracts)

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I have a setup with one contract that is a singleton and is migrated to e.g. a testnet through the truffle console.
This contract "creates" new contracts, which I want to access in the truffle console. Since the new contracts are not migrated via the console I want to use `instance.at(address)` in a command I will execute in truffle. However, it's not recognising the instance...

**Contracts:**
`Singleton.sol` → migrated via truffle
`ManyOfMe.sol` → created via Singleton.sol

**Error:**

> TypeError: ManyOfMe.at is not a function

**Code:** `run.js` executed through truffle console: `exec ./run.js`

```
const artifacts = require('./build/contracts/Singleton.json')
const ManyOfMe = require('./build/contracts/ManyOfMe.json')
const contract = require('truffle-contract')
const MyContract = contract(artifacts)
MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)

let Singleton
MyContract.deployed()
.then(async function(instance) {
  Singleton = instance

  let tokenAddress
  await Singleton.tokens(0).then(_ => {
    tokenAddress = _
  })
  return ManyOfMe.at(tokenAddress)
})
.then(function(instance) {
  instance.doSomething().then(_ => console.log(_))
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error)
})
```

PS: If I just type ManyOfMe in the truffle console, I see the `at` function, so I'm not sure why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the script with `truffle exec`, you'll already have the truffle context (e.g. `artifacts`), so you don't need to import all the stuff manually.

What you're trying to achieve is something like this here:

```
const Singleton = artifacts.require("Singleton");
const ManyOfMe = artifacts.require("ManyOfMe");

module.exports = function(done) {
    // code rewritten with async/await
    (async () => {
            var singleton = await Singleton.deployed();
            var manyOfMeAt0 = await ManyOfMe.at(await singleton.tokens(0));
            console.log(await manyOfMeAt0.doSomething());           

            done();
    })();
}
```

Moreover, if you can use `async`/`await`, then there is no need for `then`-chains. It improves the readability.

Comment: Great answer! I love the readability!
Clarified a lot for me. Final question: what's the `done()` ?

Comment: done is the signal for truffle that you've finished with your script. Since you have asnyc code here, the function returns immediatly.

Comment: Thanks man! Upvoting big time! You've been a real help. You're a peach.

Comment: You‘re welcome. Feel free to check my other answers. ;)